# why can't datepicker accept my date string in IE 7

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

My code works fine in Chrome and firefox. I am not able to get it working in IE compatibility mode. If I put the `maxDate: new Date(2012 AUG 28)` it works in IE but if I give the newDateString, changing months is disabled. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxXA5/7/)

```
endDate = "2012-09-11";
var m_names = new Array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", 
                            "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", 
                            "OCT", "NOV", "DEC");

var toDate = Date.parse(endDate) - 2592000000; 
var newToDate = new Date(toDate);

newDateString = newToDate.getFullYear() + " " + m_names[newToDate.getMonth()] + " " + newToDate.getDate();

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
     showOn: "both",
     maxDate: new Date(newDateString ),
     showAnim: "slide", 
     buttonImageOnly: true,
     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
     onSelect: function(dateTxt, inst) {
         $('#<DateForm').submit(); 
     },
     buttonText: ""
 });

$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", startDate);
```

**UPDATE**:

I have modified code to use `$.datepicker.parseDate`. I get an error in IE. It works fine in chrome and firefox

```
newDateString = newToDate.getFullYear() + " " + m_names[newToDate.getMonth()] + " " + newToDate.getDate();  

alert($.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', newDateString));
```

> Message: Exception thrown and not caught Line: 192 Char: 21310 Code: 0
>
> localhost:80/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date formats recognized by `Date.parse` vary between implementations. Instead, use `$.datepicker.parseDate`.

See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate for documentation.

Here's how to use this to subtract 30 days from the date:

```
var toDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', endDate);
toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()-30); /* Subtract 30 days */
```

Comment: OK, I have tried to use `$.datepicker.parseDate` I am getting an error in IE 7. Please see the update

Comment: Your format string doesn't match the date you're passing to `parseDate`. And you're using it in the wrong place, you need to use it in the assignment of `toDate`.

Comment: Will I be able to subtract the days if I use it in the assignment of `toDate`. I need to subtract 30 days from toDate and set it as maxDate

Comment: See edited answer, which uses Date methods to subtract 30 days.

Comment: You are genius, it works like a charm. I have been banging my head since 2 days to make it work. My initial code was similar https://forum.jquery.com/topic/date-picker-changing-months-doesn-t-work-in-ie-8. I posted on jquery forums and from one of the replies I was trying to take another route and was a big flop. With your help I am able to get it working in IE